# ¿Cómo se pronuncia "ghee" en español?

Tags: pronunciación, comida, préstamo-lingüístico

Leyendo sobre el [***ghee***](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghee) me ha entrado la duda acerca de cómo pronunciar la palabra en español. ¿Como "jee" o como "guee"?

Comment: Para los que vayan respondiendo puede ser útil utilizar la guía de guifa en [How do we show how things are pronounced?](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2588/1674).

Comment: La [pronunciación en hindi](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%98%E0%A5%80#Hindi) sería /ɡʱiː/. Dado que [/ɡʱ/](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murmured_voice) no existe en español, no habría más remedio que pronunciar "a la española".

Answer (score 3):

Pienso que debería pronunciarse como en [inglés](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ghee?pronunciation&lang=en_us&dir=g&file=ghee0001):<sup>1</sup>

> /giː/

Esto suena algo como **gui**.

---

<sup>1. Aquí es una explicación del sistema fonético a la medida que se emplea Merriam Webster: [*Guide to Pronunciation*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/assets/mw/static/pdf/help/guide-to-pronunciation.pdf)</sup>

Comment: En español sería más bien "gui"; véase la pronunciación que propone [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ghee) (que es la misma de Merriam pero con caracteres fonéticos "normales").

Answer (score 2):

## Hindi → castellano

La palabra घी (*ghee* en inglés) se pronuncia /ɡʱi/ en hindi. En castellano el consonante más semejante a /ɡʱ/ es /ɡ/, que se usa para transcribir otras palabras de origines similares:

- <sub>es</sub> [***g**avial*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=J0wziH5) ← <sub>fr</sub> ***g**avial* ← <sub>hi</sub> **घ**ड़ियाल (gaṛiyāl)

Dado esto, **"gui"** parece la forma más adecuada en castellano.

Esto coincide con la ortografia italiana de la palabra: [*ghi*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ghi/).

## Hindi → inglés → castellano

La mayoría de palabras de orígen hindi en castellano viene via inglés:

| word | Etymology |
| --- | --- |
| [búngalo](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=bungalow), [bungaló](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=bungal%C3%B3) | Del ingl. *bungalow*, y este del hindi *banglā*; propiamente 'de Bengala'. |
| [caqui](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=caqui) | Del ingl. *khaki*, este del hindi *khākī*... |
| [champú](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=champ%C3%BA) | Del ingl. *shampoo* 'champú' y 'friccionar', y este del hindi *čampī* 'masaje'. |
| [*chintz*](https://dle.rae.es/chintz) | Voz ingl., esta del hindi *chīnt* |
| [culi](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=culi) | Del ingl. *coolie*, y este del hindi *kulī* |
| [jainismo](https://dle.rae.es/jainismo) | Del ingl. *Jainism*, y este del hindi *jaina* 'santo'... |
| [jungla](https://dle.rae.es/jungla) | Del ingl. *jungle*, y este del hindi *jangal* 'terreno no cultivado'. |
| [maharaní](https://dle.rae.es/maharan%C3%AD) | Del ingl. *maharani*, este del hindi *mahārāṇī*... |
| [mudar](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=mudar) | Del ingl. *mudar*, y este del hindi *madār* |
| [ponche](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=ponche) | Del ingl. *punch*, y este del hindi *pãč*, 'cinco', número de sus ingredientes primitivos |
| [pijama](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=pijama) | Del ingl. *pyjamas*, este del hindi *pā[e]ǧāma*... |
| [sari](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=sari) | Del ingl. *sari*, y este del hindi *sāṛī*. |
| [veranda](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=veranda) | Del angloíndio *verandah*, y este del hindi *varandā* |
| [*yincana*](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=gincana) | Del angloíndio *gymkhana*, y este del hindi गेंदख़ाना *gendxānā*) <sub>Deben evitarse otras grafías que no se ajustan a su pronunciación, como **gincana, *gymkana, *gimkana*, etc.</sub> |

Así, una aproximación del inglés *ghee* i.e. **"gui"** también coincidiría con la transcripción del hindi directamente.

Answer (score 0):

Según la Wikipedia, la palabra proviene del hindi (घी), y según el [traductor de Google](https://translate.google.es/?hl=es#hi/es/%E0%A4%98%E0%A5%80) y mi oído superfino, yo entiendo que la sílaba tiene:

- un sonido consonántico que está a medio camino entre la *ch* y la *y*, y
- un sonido vocálico que parece una *i* alargada.

La verdad es no sabría si adaptarlo como "chii" o como "yii" (por usar las consonantes españolas), porque ninguna de las dos me parece lo suficientemente cercana. Pero por ahí anda la cosa.

---

EDIT: Como dice ukemi en [los comentarios](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/20369/c%C3%B3mo-se-pronuncia-ghee-en-espa%C3%B1ol/20379?noredirect=1#comment46658_20379), la pronunciación real de la palabra (que al parecer no es exactamente como dice el traductor de Google) se parece más a la sílaba *gui* del español, por lo que una adaptación más fiable sería ***guii*** si queremos respetar esa vocal alargada.

Comment: Would you find it acceptable to write _chyi-_? If I saw that it would come out much like the pronunciation my old ears heard.

Comment: @mdewey I would really have a hard time trying to figure how to pronounce that. :-)

Comment: I think you're being misled by the isolated recording on Google Translate - the sound isn't a voiced or voiceless palato-alveolar sibilant affricate `/dʒ~tʃ/`, but a [**murmured**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murmured_voice) voiced velar stop `/ɡʱ/`. Of course, murmured and aspirated consonants don't exist in Spanish, so it's easy to see how it can be misinterpreted as a different sound, but the transcriptions you're using correspond to _different_ words in Hindi: ची `/tʃi/`, जी `/dʒi/` ~ यी `/yi/`

Comment: @ukemi interesting, so you think it should be written in Spanish as _yii_?

Comment: Well, it's not a word I've ever heard used in Spanish, so I don't know what the 'usual' Spanish pronunciation is. But if you want to get as close to the original as possible, "gui" (or "guii")* should do the trick. * [some dialects of Hindi distinguish the 'long i' vowel ई ( ी ) from the short one इ ( ि ) by quality: `/i/` `/ɪ/`, some by length *and* quality: `/iː/` `/ɪ/`] (**Note:** again, this approximation is actually different word in Hindi: गी `/gi/`, but it to me (heritage speaker) sounds closer than the alternatives, and is indeed the pronunciation used in English *ghee*).

Comment: Besides what has already been said, it's very possible that /g/ before /i/ in Hindi/Urdu could become palatal or palatalized and thus produce the auditory impression reported by @ukemi. Velars turn into palatal allophones very easily (Spanish velar /x/ often becomes palatal [ç] before /i/; German /x/ does it before and after).